# Mostrar posts que incluye cada tag Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy usando la paquete rtConner que es un sistema de tags para posts. Funciona todos correctamente, pero me interesa mostrar todos los posts que inluye cada tag. Se me ocurrio hacerlo de la siguiente manera:
PostController:

```
public function Tags($tagSlug)
    {
      $tagged = Tagged::where('tag_slug', $tagSlug)->get();
      $posts = Post::where('id', $tagged->taggable_id)->get();
      

      return view('tags')->with(['tagged' => $tagged,'posts' => $posts]);
```

View:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
                     <h1>{{ $post->title}}</h1>
                  @endforeach
```

Tabla de BD donde taggable_id es el id del Post de forma foranea.
El error que me arroja es:

> Property [taggable_id] does not exist on this collection instance.

A alguien se le ocurre como resolverlo?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Algo asi no te funciona? `$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tagSlug) {
    $query->where('tag_slug', $tagSlug);
})->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema lo tienes al asignar `$tagged->taggable_id`
porque es  `$tagged` es una colección de datos.

Algo que puedes hacer para asociar de manera simple en tu vista es algo como esto

En tu blade

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   @foreach($tagged as $tag(
    <h1>{{ $tag->name}}</h1>
    @if($tag->taggable_id == $post->id)
    <h2>{{ $post->title}}</h2>
      
    @endif
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

De esta manera podrias mostrar los post que pertenecen a los tags

Pero otra recomendación es que verifiques la relación,
y si la tienes bien estructurada podrias realizar algo mas simple como:

```
 $tagged = Tagged::where('tag_slug', $tagSlug)
 ->with('posts')
 ->get();
      

 return view('tags')->with('tagged' => $tagged]);
```

En tu blade.

```
     @foreach($tagged as $tag)
          <h1>{{ $tag->name}}</h1>
        @foreach($tag->posts as $post)
        <h2>{{ $post->title}}</h2>
       @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario y tiempo, pero no me funciono. Use la primera opcion y me arroja error de offset:1

Comment: el offset ocurre cuando intentas acceder a un indice que no existe dentro del arreglo. lo cual es muy raro que suceda con los ciclos foreach

Comment: Buenas. Volvi a intentar con la primera opcion y funciono, pero solo muestra la primera coincidencia. No itera sobre el resto. Que puede ser? Gracias!

Comment: Puedes mostrar como estas tu controller y tu vista? Para tener una idea

Comment: Listo Ivan, funciono! en use la primera opcion y en mi controlador cambien la variable $posts asignando Post::all(); para que itere y encuentre la coincidencia entre todos los posts. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

La variable **`$tagged`** te esta retornando una colección, entonces no puedes simplemente tratar de acceder a la propiedad: *taggable_id*.

**Opción 1**

Aunque puedes simplificarlo en 2 pasos:

- Modifica la consulta quitando a get y usando pluck para obtener un array solo con los ids de *taggable_id*
- Modifica tu consulta para usar un whereIn, donde pases como primer argumento el id de post y como segundo argumento el array que recuperaste del paso anterior

Consulta:

```
$tagged = Tagged::where('tag_slug', $tagSlug)->pluck('taggable_id');
$posts = Post::whereIn('id', [$tagged])->get();
```

Lo anterior claro considerando que la consulta esté pensada para retornar N elementos

**Opción 2**

En caso de que estés seguro de que solo vas a retornar uno (*en la primer query*) puedes dejarla del modo siguiente:

```
$tagged = Tagged::where('tag_slug', $tagSlug)->value('taggable_id');
$posts = Post::whereId($tagged)->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, funciono, pero solo muestra un solo post (solo la primer coincidencia). Que puede ser? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo!

Comment: ¿Con qué consulta?

Comment: Hola @BetaM probe con la Opcion 1. La verdad que de todas las soluciones fue la que mejor funciono. Pero no solo me muestra el primer Post. Tenes idea porque no itera hacia los demas? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```php
$tagged = Tagged::where('tag_slug', $tagSlug)->get();
```

`$tagged` es una colección por lo que tendrías que iterarla para acceder a `taggable_id`

```php
$tagged = Tagged::where('tag_slug', $tagSlug)->get();
$posts = 0;
foreach($tagged as $tag){
        array_push($posts, Post::where('id', $tag->taggable_id)->first());
}
return view('tags')->with(['tagged' => $tagged,'posts' => $posts]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario y tiempo, pero no me funciono.